# Can I upgrade Azure Redis version 4 to version 6?

Tags: azure, redis

I heard that Microsoft will retire Azure Redis version 4. My Sitecore instance is using this resource. Am I safe to upgrade to Azure Redis version 6?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The news is correct on June 30, 2023 [Microsoft will retire version 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-whats-new#upgrade-your-azure-cache-for-redis-instances-to-use-redis-version-6-by-june-30-2023) for Azure Cache for Redis instances.

**Azure Redis cache is the default private session provider that Sitecore uses on Azure.**

According to the [Sitecore Knowledgebase](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0087164) in Sitecore XP Azure Redis is supported (without version number mentioned) and all Redis on-prem versions are expected to work correctly.

The [system requirements for a Sitecore XC 10.3](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/sitecore-experience-commerce/system-requirements.html) hosting environment mention that Azure Redis version 4.0.14 or later is needed and supported.

***So based on the above you should be safe to upgrade your Azure Redis instance.***

You can upgrade your Redis using the Azure portal:

1. In the Azure portal, select the Azure Cache for Redis instance that
   you want to upgrade from Redis 4 to Redis 6.
2. On the left side of the
   screen, select Advanced settings. If your cache instance is eligible
   to be upgraded, you should see the following blue banner. If you
   want to proceed, select the text in the banner.

[image: [img1]]

3. A dialog box displays a popup notifying you that upgrading is permanent and might cause a brief connection blip. Select Yes if you would like to upgrade your cache instance.

[image: [img2]]

To upgrade to Redis 6 you can also follow this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-upgrade

**UPDATE:**

Sitecore released a [Knowledge Base article](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1002935) to cover this topic,
including a statement: *"Microsoft has stated that version 6 is compatible with version 4, and no changes are required in client applications to ensure compatibility."*

Sitecore also released a [service update for Managed Cloud](https://support.sitecore.com/status?id=pub&sysid=780f9c901bb1e510722d4042b24bcbf3), which states that you can update the instances yourself or if you need any further assistance, please raise a new support ticket on [Sitecore support portal](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0654910).

Comment: Will Sitecore's Cloud Ops team be responsible for Redis upgrades in the Managed Cloud environment? Possibly via Service Request?

Comment: @ChetCheeto Sitecore released a service update which states that you can update the instances yourself or if you need any further assistance, please raise a new support ticket on Sitecore support portal.

More information: https://support.sitecore.com/status?id=pub&sysid=780f9c901bb1e510722d4042b24bcbf3